# Twilio prints sid but it is no longer sending the messages

Tags: python, twilio, whatsapp

I use the twilio API to write a simple program to remember my father to take his meds. Here is my code which can be replicated by anyone who has an account in twilio, one phone number and the sheet `medications.csv`(see bellow):

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
import re

account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' #INSERT YOUR SID HERE
auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' #INSERT YOUR TOKEN HERE
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

def to_list_integer(dt_time):
    return [dt_time.year,dt_time.month,dt_time.day, dt_time.hour,dt_time.minute]



df=pd.read_csv('medications.csv')

while True:
    data_lista =  to_list_integer(datetime.now())
    x=datetime(*data_lista)
    hora = x.strftime("%Hh%M")
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if (datetime.now().hour==df['hour'][i]) & (datetime.now().minute==df['minute'][i]) & (datetime.now().second==1):
            text = '''*Lembrete: {0}*\n
Olá sr. X, agora são {1}, 
\nestá na hora de tomar {2} comprimido(s) de {0}
\n\n*recomendação médica: {3}*'''.format(df['name'][i],hora,re.search(r'\d+',df['recomendation'][i]).group(),
                                                df['recomendation'][i])
            persons=['whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX','whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX','whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXXXX']
            for person in persons:
                message = client.messages.create(
                                            body=text,
                                            from_='whatsapp:+XXXXXXXXXXX',#INSERT YOUR TWILIO NUMBER HERE
                                            to=person
                                        )
            print(message.sid)
```

`medications.csv`:

```
name,dosage,recomendation,hour,minute
Selozek,100mg,Tomar 1 comprimido pela manhã,6,9
Vasopril Plus,20/12.5 mg,Tomar 1 comprimido pela manhã,6,10
Glifage XR,500mg,Tomar 2 comprimidos após o café e após a última refeição da noite,7,10
Clopidogrel,75mg,Tomar 1 comprimido após o almoço,13,10
AAS,100mg,Tomar 1 comprimido após o almoço,13,11
Enalapril,10mg,Tomar 2 comprimidos à noite,20,10
Glifage XR,500mg,Tomar 2 comprimidos após o café e após a última refeição da noite,20,11
Rosuvastatina,20mg,Tomar 1 comprimido após a última refeição da noite,20,12
```

The code was working properly yesterday but today it is no longer working. The program runs without errors and print the sids for each message. However, none of the phones in the list `persons` are receiving the message. What is wrong here?

Comment: It looks like that the user must answer the message in order to keep receiving updates, otherwise the application crashs: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017773294-Rules-and-Best-Practices-for-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio Is there an API without this restirctions?

Comment: It is a WhatsApp requirement, the 24 hour free-form window. You would need to initiate via a template outside that window, to start a conversation to a WhatsApp user, https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates. You would need to use something other then that if not possible, like SMS.